# What qualifies as a "monocolored creature"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm a little confused about what a "monocolored creature" is.

[Defiler of Souls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189646) is definitely not, having a mana cost of 3BBR - Black and red is definitely not monocolored.

[Birds of Paradise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221896) definitely is monocolored, having a mana cost of G.

[Soulfire Grand Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391927) has a mana cost of 1W - this is where my uncertainty lies. Is this a monocolored creature because of the single (W), or does the (1) disqualify that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Soulfire Grand Master is monocolored. Monocolored cards have exactly one color of mana in their cost. Colorless does not count as a color. So, a cost of 1 white and 1 colorless mana contains only one color - white. Of course, anything that specifically alters a card's color overrides this general rule.

> **105.2.** An object can be one or more of the five colors, or it can be no color at all. An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame. An object’s color or colors may also be defined by a color indicator or a characteristic-defining ability.
>
> **105.2a** A monocolored object is exactly one of the five colors.
>
> **105.4.** ... “Multicolored” is not a color. Neither is “colorless.”

Comment: Thanks. `Colorless does not count as a color` explains it perfectly.

Comment: Especially with devoid being a thing now, I'd suggest updating "Monocolored cards have only one color of mana in their cost."

Comment: @user2959229 Except that number-and-gray-circle mana symbol in a cost is actually *generic* mana, not colorless mana. It doesn't have to be paid with colorless mana, and colored mana doesn't turn colorless when you pay it. Still, that generic mana symbol doesn't have a color, so you get the same result: the colored mana symbols in a cost (or lack thereof) determine the color.

Comment: @DavidZ - Not to mention all the cards with color indicators (Dryad Arbor, transformed cards, etc.)

Comment: @DavidZ Maybe, but honestly, devoid will only be a thing for a little while. This answer will last much longer than devoid popular in virtually anyone's mind.

Comment: @corsiKa I only offered devoid as the most prevalent example of cards whose color is not determined by their mana cost. I would expect the general idea of such cards to keep popping up every now and then for a long time.